# How to test if location is a btrfs subvolume?

Tags: bash, btrfs

In bash scripting, how could I check elegantly if a specific location is a btrfs subvolume?

I do NOT want to know if the given location is *in* a btrfs file system (or subvolume). I want to know if the given location is *the head of* a subvolume.

Ideally, the solution could be written in a bash function so I could write:

```
if is_btrfs_subvolume $LOCATION; then
    # ... stuff ...
fi
```

An 'elegant' solution would be readable, small in code, small in resource consumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution1:** Using @kdave suggestions:

```
is_btrfs_subvolume() {
    local dir=$1
    [ "$(stat -f --format="%T" "$dir")" == "btrfs" ] || return 1
    inode="$(stat --format="%i" "$dir")"
    case "$inode" in
        2|256)
            return 0;;
        *)
            return 1;;
    esac
}
```

**Solution2:** What I used before (only one call, but probably brittle):

```
is_btrfs_subvolume() {
    btrfs subvolume show "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

**EDIT:** Corrected and replaced `list` by `show` as the behavior of `list` would not answer correctly on any normal `btrfs` directory.

**EDIT2:** as @kdave didn't post a full version of his superior answer, I added it to my answer.

Comment: This function is not worked.  For my case, $1 is any directory exist in a btrfs partition, will always return all subvolume list in this partition, altough, $1 is just a normal directory. if current directory is a subvolume, this directory will list as the last line of list, otherwise, not. I don't know how to down the answer ...

Comment: Oh, yes, good catch. Sorry, I replaced 'list' by 'show'. Is it working as it should now ?

Comment: You should run your script as root.

Comment: Is this still working for you? The command correctly identifies subvolumes but is always returning 0 for me meaning I can't use it programatically.

Comment: @TomWadley still working here. What version of ``btrfs-tools`` are you using ? (``btrfs --version``... I'm on ``v4.10.1``.)

Comment: @vaab I'm on `v3.17` (Debian 8.7) so that might explain it. I can only get it to return 1 by passing in a path that doesn't exist at all. @kdave's `stat` solution works fine though.

Answer (score 17):

The subvolume is identified by inode number 256, so you can check it simply by

```
if [ `stat --format=%i /path` -eq 256 ]; then ...; fi
```

There's also a so called empty-subvolume, ie. if a nested subvolume is snapshotted, this entity will exist in place of the original subvolume. Its inode number is 2.

For a generally reliable check wheter any directory is a subvolume, the filesystem type should be verified as well

```
stat -f --format=%T /path
```

Comment: All this seems overly complicated compared to the current provided solution, and brittle if any new inode number gets used, isn't it ?. Anyway, I like the additional peripheral information you provided, there might be actually a good solution hidding not so far.

Comment: The command "btrfs subvolume list" requires root privileges because it uses a privileged ioctl to read the information about subvolumes, this was not menionted in the original answer. The inode number based test does not have such limitation.
Next, I don't understand what do you mean by "brittle if any new inode number gets used". Each subvolume has inode number 256, this will not change. Regular files and directories in a subvolume have inode number 257 and higher.

Comment: You are right. Your answer is nice and misses only the bash function implementation (that was originally asked) and it would also be a nice TLDR summary of the test.

Comment: Looking at the inode number does not allow you to distinguish a subvolume of the same btrfs filesystem from a different btrfs filesystem mounted in a directory. Both appear with inode 256.

Comment: Can a file or directory in other filesystems have inode 256? And if so, I suppose we will need to perform an additional check. (Perhaps to confirm from `/etc/mtab` that the path is btrfs mounted, which also doesn't need root access.)